# sum values in a column with awk

Tags: awk

Hi all I have a file which looks like this:

```
AAAA  5
BBBB  4
CCCC  12
...
```

(the file is tab separated and many 1000's of lines)

What I am interested in doing is summing the second column of values, which is straight forward:

```
awk '{sum +=$2}END{print sum}'
```

Which in the case of these 3 rows would give a value of 21. What I want to do is to first sum all of the 2nd column in the file, then print col1, col2, col2/sum. So the output would look like this:

```
AAAA 5 0.2380
BBBB 4 0.1904
CCCC 12 0.5714
```

What I have tried is this:

```
awk '{sum +=$2}END{print $1,$2,$2/sum}'
```

But it doesn't seem to work, all I get is "CCCC 12 0.5714" to be printed. I have been trying to figure this out, but can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{val[$1]=$2; sum+=$2} END{for (key in val) print key, val[key], (sum?val[key]/sum:0)}' file
CCCC 12 0.571429
BBBB 4 0.190476
AAAA 5 0.238095
```

To keep the input order:

```
$ awk '!($1 in val){keys[++numKeys]=$1} {val[$1]=$2; sum+=$2} END{for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys;keyNr++) { key=keys[keyNr]; print key, val[key], (sum?val[key]/sum:0)} }' file
AAAA 5 0.238095
BBBB 4 0.190476
CCCC 12 0.571429
```

and to format the number:

```
$ awk '!($1 in val){keys[++numKeys]=$1} {val[$1]=$2; sum+=$2} END{for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys;keyNr++) { key=keys[keyNr]; printf "%s %d %.4f\n", key, val[key], (sum?val[key]/sum:0)} }' file
AAAA 5 0.2381
BBBB 4 0.1905
CCCC 12 0.5714
```